# Queryset foreign key models

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have two models below which one of the models inherits a foreign key from the model

```
class Services(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)


class Order(models.Model):

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
```

I want to get the value of the total value of orders per service (per instance)

So for example

if the id = 1 of service has made orders of £10, £33, etc. I would like to get the total value of that of that service based on how many orders it has been made.

So far I have made an queryset below

```
Order.objects.all().values_list('service__price')
```

Which provides me the list of prices, but I would like the total per instance of service.

How would one achieve this?

Comment: Please can you clarify "the id = 1 of service has made orders of £10, £33, etc". Any instance of `Service` has only one associated price, the one which is a property of the `Service` object itself, so how can these orders have different prices? There is no other price referenced in the `Order` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question is wrong due to the wrong model design. 
If you want to have a service but with different prices you need to put price on you order table.

Change your models to :

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)


class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, related_name='orders')
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

Then you can query your sum of prices for one service:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

s = Service.objects.get(id=1)
s.orders.all().aggregate(Sum("price"))
```